# String.replace() method not printing full string in java

Tags: java, eclipse, string, replace

I'm trying to do some homework for my computer science class and I can't seem to figure this one out. The question is:

> Write a program that reads a line of text and then displays the line, but with the first occurrence of *hate* changed to *love*.

This sounded like a basic problem, so I went ahead and wrote this up:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");

        String text = keyboard.next();

        System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
        System.out.println(text.replaceFirst("hate", "love"));
    }
}
```

I expect a string input of "I hate you" to read "I love you", but all it outputs is "I". When it detects the first occurrence of the word I'm trying to replace, it removes the rest of the string, unless it's the first word of the string. For instance, if I just input "hate", it will change it to "love". I've looked at many sites and documentations, and I believe I'm following the correct steps. If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong here so that it does display the full string with the replaced word, that would be fantastic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the whole line like this, instead of just the first token:

```
String text = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was on the [`keyboard.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) call.  This reads the first (space-separated) word.  You want to use [`keyboard.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) instead, as that reads a whole line (which is what your input is in this case).

Revised, your code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");

        String text = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
        System.out.println(text.replaceFirst("hate", "love"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`keyboard.next()` only reads the next token.
Use `keyboard.nextLine()` to read the entire line.
In your current code, if you print the contents of `text` before the `replace` you will see that only `I` has been taken as input.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate answer, build a while loop and look for the word in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
      // Start with the word we want to replace
        String findStr = "hate";
      // and the word we will replace it with
        String replaceStr = "love";
      // Need a place to put the response
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");
        System.out.println("<Remember to end the stream with Ctrl-Z>");

        String text = null;
        while(keyboard.hasNext())
        {
          // Make sure we have a space between characters
          if(text != null)
          {
            response.append(' ');
          }
          text = keyboard.next();
          if(findStr.compareToIgnoreCase(text)==0)
          {
            // Found the word so replace it
            response.append(replaceStr);
          }
          else
          {
            // Otherwise just return what was entered.
            response.append(text);
          }
        }

        System.out.println("I have rephrased that line to read:");
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
}
```

Takes advantage of the Scanner returning one word at a time.  The matching will fail if the word is followed by a punctuation mark though.  Anyway, this is the answer that popped into my head when I read the question.